# RestRequest and Square Connect

Tags: c#, restsharp, square-connect

I am running the following code:

```
var client = new RestClient();
var request = new RestRequest("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/payments", Method.GET) 
{ 
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json 
};
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXX");
var Response = client.Execute(request);
```

The response error message states:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot try this currently, so I'm not sure it will be the fix you are looking for, but it's just a thought: try to initialize the `RestClient` with the Uri string, and the `RestRequest` with the rest of the string, or with empty string, like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/payments");
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.GET)
{ 
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json 
};
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXX");
var Response = client.Execute(request);
```